# Convert Table Data to Dataframe and Filter

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am scraping Over/Under Odds data from this Website:https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/uruguay/segunda-division/juventud-sud-america-I1G8VYUr/?r=1#over-under;2;6.50;0

The scraping happens as follows:

```
url='https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/chile/primera-division/curico-unido-o-higgins-CtsLggl6/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get(url)
    overunder=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='Over/Under']").click()
browser.maximize_window()
    
odds_rows = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.table-header-light')))

    for i in odds_rows:
        count = i.find_element_by_xpath('./span[@class="odds-cnt"]')
        elem = i.find_elements_by_xpath('.//[contains(text(),"Compare")]')
        txt = count.text

        if txt != '' and len(elem):
            elem = elem[0]
            browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem)
            elem.click()
```

I am looping through multiple match pages and scraping the Over/Under odds data for multiple betting providers which is stored in a table:[Odds Table][1]

The data is stored in the class table-container, which I have scraped:

```
table_src=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.table-container')))
```

Next I am trying to parse this data out into rows and columns:

```
appended_data=[]
for i in table_src:
    html_src=i.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    soup= BeautifulSoup(html_src,'html.parser')
    tab_data = [[cell.text for cell in row.find_all(["th","td"])]
                       for row in soup.find_all("tr")]
```

Next I am trying to add this into a Dataframe:

```
    appended_data.append(tab_data)
    # df = pd.DataFrame(tab_data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(appended_data)
```

However this leaves me with a very strange and convoluted DF:[Dataframe][2]

As can be seen the dataframe has a lot of columns.. Ideally I would like to have the DF with only these columns:
Bookmaker, Total, Over, Under, Payout

Then I would like to filter for two specific bookmakers like so:

```
   appended_data.loc[appended_data['0'].isin(bookmakers)]
```

What am I missing to make this work?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmadi.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJcqo.png

Comment: Please edit your question so it is a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There should be no images. Also, the runnable code snippet aren't helpful here. Just have normal formatted code

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! I have adjusted the question accordingly, I hope it is clearer now